# Error running a brand new Blazor App with .NET Core 6.0

Tags: .net-core, blazor

In Visual Studio 2022, I create a new Blazor WebAssembly App. VS does its thing and scaffolds the project with a .sln file. I hit the Run button and I'm met with `error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'MyBlazorApp' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Interestingly, this doesn't show up in my Error List window, just as a build output. Googling is only showing me some people having a similar problem with older versions of .NET Core, and the solution in most cases is to update VS2019. Is it possible this is the same bug cropping up again in a new version of VS?

Comment: This shouldn't happen, so therefore (politely) you must be doing something wrong..  Can you push your virgin project to a public Github Repo?

Comment: Yeah, I can. Just to be clear, I have literally not touched a single line of code. Just created the app and hit 'go': https://github.com/brendan-mcmahon/MyBlazorApp

Comment: Some maybe relevant info: I found this issue when a friend asked me to look at his project and I couldn't get it to run with the same issue. I created a new app to try and isolate the error, and it turns out I couldn't even begin. I suspect it's something to do with Visual Studio, but I have no proof

Answer (score 1):

This is not the answer per se, but as usual I need more than the comment space available:

1. Check what version of dotnet you are running  run : `dotnet --version`.

I have:

```
PS C:\Users\shaun\Documents\GitHub\Blazr\Blazr.Demo Sites\MyBlazorApp> dotnet --version
6.0.101
PS C:\User
```

2. Downgrade the packages in the project file and check whether the project builds and runs.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly" Version="6.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.DevServer" Version="6.0.1" PrivateAssets="all" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: Looks like I'm running `6.0.200`, which also happens to be the version in my csproj file.

Comment: I don't know why I didn't think to try this before, but if I just use a powershell window and run `dotnet run`, it works perfectly. Whatever is happening, it's definitely a visual studio issue.

Comment: And as you might expect, running without debugging in VS does work

Comment: If you have VS Code installed, open the project folder in VS code and then run `dotnet run` from there - that's what I actually did.  I just checked your project on my Visual Studio 6.0.2 machine and it runs OK.  So I think you need to sort Visual Studio.

Comment: Comment on your last comment.  My VS with latest updates ran fine in debug mode, so it's not a generic issue.  Did you try with 6.0.1 packages?

Comment: Yeah, running it works fine, it's debugging that's the issue. Also, I did try with 6.0.1 and I'm getting the same results :-/